# A teacher gave her students a paper square. The first student cut this square into two shapes, using one straight cut not through

Tags: geometry

A teacher gave her students a paper square. The first student cut this
square into two shapes, using one straight cut not through any of the
paper’s corners. The second student cut one of the resulting shapes,
using one straight cut not through any of that shape’s corners, and so
on. After ten students had made their cuts, there were eleven shapes,
including seven triangles, two quadrilaterals, and a pentagon. How
many sides were in the remaining shape?

Comment: Hint: What happens to the total number of sides after each cut?

Comment: Hi! To avoid down-votes and close-votes, please provide us some context for this question, such as: (a) Is this homework? (b) If so, what course are you taking? (c) What specific topic are you covering at the moment? (d) What do you know that you think might be connected? (e) If you're stuck, what are you stuck on? For example, do you know what to apply, but don't know how to apply it, or do you not know what to apply? Please [edit] these facts into your original post, not as responses to this comment, as comments may be deleted without warning.

Answer (score 2):

The remaining shape has ten sides, as the amount of total sides goes up by 4 each time someone cuts a shape in two. This is because two sides are added by splitting the sides that the cut starts and ends on, and two more sides are added because of the two new sides along the cut. This results in forty new sides added, as ten students cut the paper. If we add this to the four sides we started with, we get fourty-four total sides. If we add up the total number of sides from all the other shapes ( 7 * 3 + 2 * 4 + 5 = 21 + 8 + 5 = 34 ), we can subtract this from the total number of sides ( 44 - 34 = 10 ), and thus, we are left with the number of remaining sides, or the number of sides in the remaining shape, ten.